# The best way to schedule||automate MarkLogic data hub flows/custom steps

Tags: gradle, marklogic, orchestrate

I use DMSDK to ingest data; I have multiple custom flows to run following data ingestion. Instead of manually running the flows one by one, What is the best way to orchestrate MarkLogic data hub flows? 
gradle, trigger or other scheduling tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I concur with Dave Cassel that NiFi, or perhaps something like MuleSoft, or maybe even Camel is a great way to manage running your flows. Particularly if you are talking about operational management.

To answer on other mechanisms:

- Crontab doesn't connect to MarkLogic itself. You'd have to write scripts or code to make something actually happen. You won't have much control either, nor logging, unless you add that as well.
- We have great plugins for Gradle that make running flows real easy. Great during development and such, but perhaps less suited for scheduling or operational tasking.
- Triggers inside MarkLogic only respond to insertion of data, so you'd still have to initiate an update from outside anyhow.
- Scheduled Tasks inside MarkLogic has similar limitations to Crontab and Gradle. It doesn't do much by itself, so you have to write code anyhow. It provides no logging by itself, nor ways to operationally manage the tasks, other than through Admin ui.
- JAR package might depend on what JAR package you actually mean. You can create a JAR of your ml-gradle project, but that doesn't give you a lot of gain over calling Gradle itself.

Personally, I'd have a close look at the operational requirements. Think of for instance: need to get status overview, interrupt schedules, loops to retry at failure, built-in logging, and facilities to send notifications when attention is needed.

HTH!

Comment: Thanks! From operational standpoint: 1) control-M can schedule/monitor pretty much every job flow or tasks and control the job dependency...etc. This is a typical Production approach  2) JAR package is the new approach I am looking at. Because it might potentially orchestrate all of the MarkLogic and Gradle related events/tasks with minimum scripting efforts, giving the fact that DMSDK is outside of the Gradle. 3) If Nifi can schedule/monitor both event driven and time driven tasks in a very stable fashion, I may consider that as well.

Comment: I've used NiFi mostly for time-driven tasks. You can set it up to check whether a new condition has occurred (eg, hit a REST endpoint and continue if you get an interesting response; else stop). You can also talk to NiFi through its REST API, so some other service could tell NiFi to begin processing.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of answers that will work, of course; my preference is NiFi. This keeps any scheduling overhead outside of MarkLogic, with the trade-off that you'll need to have NiFi running.

Comment: Does other option work well based on your experience?   crontab, gradle, JAR package, or ML scheduled tasks(not my favor) ?   Please elaborate.

Comment: Came here to respond only to find @grtjn's excellent response. To add -- scheduled tasks are also volatile data -- if the server restarts for any reason, Tasks on the Task Queue are lost. When NiFi restarts, it picks up where it left off.